# How to hide several classes but individually after click it with JS DOM. New on JS & having a hard time

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, anchor, hide

By example I have a list of classes which the class "ld-certificate-link" will be called "brod" and it has an icon which it is represented with a white style color and what I wish to do is that when I click the icon the class disappears.

The problem is that when I select the query or it only affect one "brod" and the next ones doesn't change the color at all or the second case scenario is that only by clicking one it change the color of every "brod". Also notice that "brod" has an href which is dynamic and unique because it spawns after a quiz is submitted so what happens when you click "brod" is that the href which is a .pdf file automatically downloads. Also this has to work into every new brod that is generated. Any hints? I'm pretty new on JS and I'm doing my best but I'm having a hard time on this.

The most close code that I get is this one:

Html:

```html
<div class="ld-item-list-item ld-item-list-item-course ld-expandable learndash-complete ld-expanded" id="ld-course-list-item-42634">
    <div class="ld-item-list-item-preview">

        <a href="https://xxxxxxx.com/courses/prueba-ii/" class="ld-item-name">
            <div class="ld-status-icon ld-status-complete ld-secondary-background"><span class="ld-icon-checkmark ld-icon"></span></div>            <span class="ld-course-title">Prueba II</span>
        </a> <!--/.ld-course-name-->

        <div class="ld-item-details">

                            <a class="ld-certificate-link" target="_blank" href="https://xxxxxxx.com/certificates/35472/?course_id=42634&amp;cert-nonce=9c8a79d8ae" aria-label="Certificado" download=""><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-certificate"></span></a>
            
            <div class="ld-status ld-status-complete ld-secondary-background">Completo</div>
            <div class="ld-expand-button ld-primary-background ld-compact ld-not-mobile ld-expanded" data-ld-expands="ld-course-list-item-42634">
                <span class="ld-icon-arrow-down ld-icon"></span>
            </div> <!--/.ld-expand-button-->

            <div class="ld-expand-button ld-button-alternate ld-mobile-only ld-expanded" data-ld-expands="ld-course-list-item-42634" data-ld-expand-text="Desplegar" data-ld-collapse-text="Contraer">
                <span class="ld-icon-arrow-down ld-icon"></span>
                <span class="ld-text ld-primary-color">Contraer</span>
            </div> <!--/.ld-expand-button-->

        </div> <!--/.ld-course-details-->

    </div> <!--/.ld-course-preview-->
    <div class="ld-item-list-item-expanded" data-height="604" style="max-height: 604px;">

        <div class="ld-progress" style="">
    <div class="ld-progress-heading">
        <div class="ld-progress-label">Proceso de Capacitación      </div>
        <div class="ld-progress-stats">
            <div class="ld-progress-percentage ld-secondary-color">100% Completado          </div> <!--/.ld-course-progress-percentage-->
            <div class="ld-progress-steps"> 1/1 pasos           </div>
        </div> <!--/.ld-course-progress-stats-->
    </div> <!--/.ld-course-progress-heading-->

    <div class="ld-progress-bar">
        <div class="ld-progress-bar-percentage ld-secondary-background" style="width: 100%;"></div>
    </div> <!--/.ld-course-progress-bar-->
</div> <!--/.ld-course-progress-->

            <div class="ld-item-contents">

                <div class="ld-table-list ld-quiz-list">
    <div class="ld-table-list-header ld-primary-background">
        <div class="ld-table-list-title">
            Evaluaciones        </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-title-->
        <div class="ld-table-list-columns">
                    <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-column-certificate">
                Certificado         </div>
                    <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-column-scores">
                Calificación            </div>
                    <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-column-stats">
                Estadísticas            </div>
                    <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-column-date">
                Fecha           </div>
                </div>
    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-header-->

    <div class="ld-table-list-items">
        
<div class="ld-table-list-item passed">
    <div class="ld-table-list-item-preview">

        <div class="ld-table-list-title">
            <a href="https://xxxxxxx.com/quizzes/examen-final-prueba-ii/"><div class="ld-status-icon ld-quiz-complete ld-secondary-color"><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-quiz"></span></div><span>EXAMEN FINAL PRUEBA II</span></a>
        </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-title-->

        <div class="ld-table-list-columns">

                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-certificate ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Certificado: </span>
                    <a class="ld-certificate-link" href="https://xxxxxxx.com/certificates/35472-2/?quiz=42637&amp;cert-nonce=d8b4a067d0&amp;time=1628218385" target="_new" aria-label="Certificado" download=""><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-certificate"></span></a>               </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-scores ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Calificación: </span>
                    100%                </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-stats ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Estadísticas: </span>
                    <a class="user_statistic" data-statistic-nonce="e13a3ca2a2" data-user-id="1" data-quiz-id="29" data-ref-id="306" href="#"><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-assignment"></span></a>              </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-date ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Fecha: </span>
                    05/08/2021 23:53                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-item-preview-->

    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-item-->

<div class="ld-table-list-item passed">
    <div class="ld-table-list-item-preview">

        <div class="ld-table-list-title">
            <a href="https://xxxxxxx.com/quizzes/examen-final-prueba-ii/"><div class="ld-status-icon ld-quiz-complete ld-secondary-color"><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-quiz"></span></div><span>EXAMEN FINAL PRUEBA II</span></a>
        </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-title-->

        <div class="ld-table-list-columns">

                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-certificate ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Certificado: </span>
                    <a class="ld-certificate-link" href="https://xxxxxxx.com/certificates/35472-2/?quiz=42637&amp;cert-nonce=d8b4a067d0&amp;time=1628266530" target="_new" aria-label="Certificado" download=""><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-certificate"></span></a>               </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-scores ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Calificación: </span>
                    100%                </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-stats ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Estadísticas: </span>
                    <a class="user_statistic" data-statistic-nonce="1fa17abf9e" data-user-id="1" data-quiz-id="29" data-ref-id="307" href="#"><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-assignment"></span></a>              </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-date ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Fecha: </span>
                    06/08/2021 13:15                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-item-preview-->

    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-item-->

<div class="ld-table-list-item passed">
    <div class="ld-table-list-item-preview">

        <div class="ld-table-list-title">
            <a href="https://xxxxxxx.com/quizzes/examen-final-prueba-ii/"><div class="ld-status-icon ld-quiz-complete ld-secondary-color"><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-quiz"></span></div><span>EXAMEN FINAL PRUEBA II</span></a>
        </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-title-->

        <div class="ld-table-list-columns">

                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-certificate ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Certificado: </span>
                    <a class="ld-certificate-link" href="https://xxxxxxx.com/certificates/35472-2/?quiz=42637&amp;cert-nonce=d8b4a067d0&amp;time=1628266609" target="_new" aria-label="Certificado" download=""><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-certificate"></span></a>               </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-scores ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Calificación: </span>
                    100%                </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-stats ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Estadísticas: </span>
                    <a class="user_statistic" data-statistic-nonce="28dc605682" data-user-id="1" data-quiz-id="29" data-ref-id="308" href="#"><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-assignment"></span></a>              </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-date ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Fecha: </span>
                    06/08/2021 13:16                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-item-preview-->

    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-item-->

<div class="ld-table-list-item passed">
    <div class="ld-table-list-item-preview">

        <div class="ld-table-list-title">
            <a href="https://xxxxxxx.com/quizzes/examen-final-prueba-ii/"><div class="ld-status-icon ld-quiz-complete ld-secondary-color"><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-quiz"></span></div><span>EXAMEN FINAL PRUEBA II</span></a>
        </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-title-->

        <div class="ld-table-list-columns">

                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-certificate ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Certificado: </span>
                    <a class="ld-certificate-link" href="https://xxxxxxx.com/certificates/35472-2/?quiz=42637&amp;cert-nonce=d8b4a067d0&amp;time=1628266639" target="_new" aria-label="Certificado" download=""><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-certificate"></span></a>               </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-scores ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Calificación: </span>
                    100%                </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-stats ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Estadísticas: </span>
                    <a class="user_statistic" data-statistic-nonce="5bdb484223" data-user-id="1" data-quiz-id="29" data-ref-id="309" href="#"><span class="ld-icon ld-icon-assignment"></span></a>              </div>
                            <div class="ld-table-list-column ld-table-list-column-date ">
                    <span class="ld-column-label">Fecha: </span>
                    06/08/2021 13:17                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-item-preview-->

    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-item-->
    </div> <!--/.ld-table-list-items-->

    <div class="ld-table-list-footer"></div>

</div> <!--/.ld-quiz-list-->

                
            </div> <!--/.ld-course-contents-->

        
    </div> <!--/.ld-course-list-item-expanded-->

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('brod')
    .addEventListener("click", handleClick );
    
    function handleClick() {
      alert("i got clicked!");
    }
    
    var doShow = localStorage.getItem('.brod');
    if (doShow == null) {
      doShow = true;
    }
    const anchor = document.querySelector('.brod');
    if (doShow == "false") {
      anchor.style.display = "none";
    }
    
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
      localStorage.setItem('.brod', "false");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can give a full correct answer without seeing all of your HTML.

I do think part of the issue is that you need to loop over all the instances of .brod and apply your code to all of them. Currently your are only querying one instance of .brod

For example:

```
let allBrods = document.querySelectorAll('.brod');

[].forEach.call(allBrods, function(brod) {
  brod.addEventListener("click", handleClick );
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate i will post the html too, and change the brod to the class set on the html to see we can do.